# Bibliography issues using llnc/splncs04

Tags: bibliographies, lncs

I'm using the LLNC macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings, version 2.20.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
.
.
\cite{paper}
.
.
\bibliography{references}
```

I get the following error message:

> I couldn't open style file splncs04.bst
>   ---line 28 of file Draft_1.aux
>    : \bibstyle{splncs04
>    :                   }
>   I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
>   I found no style file---while reading file Draft_1.aux

I went through other similar questions here on llnc/splncs04 but couldnt find a fix for the bibliography.
I use TeXstudio.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). For future questions, please consider adding a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) since here, the code snippet you provide is not compilable and another user cannot reproduce your error. However, here, the error seems to be pretty straightforward: consider creating a file `splncs04.bst` in your working folder and putting the file [here](http://grammars.grlmc.com/AlCoB2018/Download/splncs04.bst) inside.

Comment: Will keep those points in mind.

I created the `.bst` file and it works! Thank you.